# What do I need to enable to run sar -d?

Tags: ubuntu, sar

When I run sar -d I receive the error message:

> Requested activities not available in
>   file /var/log/sysstat/sa24

The file does exist, and I can run sar with other flags, but can't see these particular metrics.  Is there something I need to enable in sysstat to collect what I need to see this report?

Server is Ubuntu 9.04.

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled it in: `/etc/default/sysstat` and made sure that `SA1_OPTIONS="-S DISK"` is not commented out?

Since you said you can get other information, I assume it is started it with `/etc/init.d/sysstat start`?

Comment: I did start sysstat with /etc/init.d/sysstat start, and /etc/default/sysstat contains the lines:

ENABLED="true"
SA1_OPTIONS="-S DISK"
SA2_OPTIONS=""

Maybe there ore other options I should have in SA1_OPTIONS or SA2_OPTIONS?

Comment: That all works with my workstation (non-server).  Maybe try stopping sysstat, moving the sa24 file somewhere else, and restarting sysstat? Perhaps your io device is a little bit non-standard and is not in `sysstat.ioconf` ?

Comment: I just tried this on a testing Ubuntu Server VM I have to make sure that there weren't any issues with apparmour but there weren't any.  All I had to do was make the appropriate changes in /etc/default/sysstat and run sudo /etc/init.d/sysstat start

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak for ubuntu but for red hat you have to change how it collects data in /usr/crond./sysstat:

from: /usr/lib/sa/sa1 1 1

to: /usr/lib/sa/sa1 -d 1 1

The -d says to collect disk stats.  sa1 just calls /usr/lib/sa/sadc, if you want to see the doc for it do a man sadc.

This change doesn't take affect until the next time sa2 runs (I think).  I always set it and then it starts collecting and working the next day.

Answer (score 1):

I think sar -d is activated as default on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6+ but not on 5 (I don't know about other distributions).

On RHEL 6 I edited a line in /etc/cron.d/sysstat to contain the "-d" option:

> */10 * * * * root /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 -d 1 1

Note: the "-S DISK" option, which is the default in RHEL 6+ (sysstat-9.0.4-18) did not work for RHEL 5 (sysstat-7.0.2-11).

The additional data is collected as soon as a new sa file is created the next day. If you are in a hurry, you could probably just delete today's sa file under /var/log/sa - but I did not try that out myself.

Answer (score 1):

in debian based systems you have to set SA1_OPTIONS="-S DISK -S POWER -S ..." in `/etc/sysstat/sysstat`

You can also set `-S XALL` to collect all information

see `man 8 sdac` - there is also the following important note:

> Important note: The activities (including optional ones) saved in an existing data file prevail over those selected with option -S.  As a consequence, appending data to an existing data file will result in option -S being ignored.

Meaning, if todays sysstat-file already exists (e.g.: `/var/log/sysstat/sa17`) you have to remove that file first. So that sysstat can fill the new file with the additional information from `-S DISK`

(you could create a file manually with sdac, but deleting todays sysstat file ist easier)

(sidenote: to use `-S POWER` which will give you `sar -m FAN` or `sar -m TEMP` output, you have to install `lm-sensors` and run `sensors-detect` successfully)

Answer (score 0):

there is no file :sysstat  in the /etc/init/d directory, the ekernel version is 2.6.18-164.el5
and the sar -d is not working:"Requested activities not available in file /var/log/sa/sa11"